# DocuSign - redirect to finish page after embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using this API `POST /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient` to embed docusign to my application but I encounter some issue after signing the document. Please see below for the screenshot

- This is the view when I signed the document
  [image]
- When I click "**Finish**" button, I encounter this issue below:
  [image]
  [image]

I tried to fix the problem by inserting this line of code in the HTML header

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

But I encounter different error when clicking again "**Finish**" button, see screenshot below

[image]
[image]

Any idea how to fix this issue, btw I'm using iframe to embed docusign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first off, we (DocuSign) urge you to not use an iFrame. There is no need for an iFrame and it can cause you issues (like the ones you're experiencing.)

And using an iFrame prevents you from using the [Identity Verification](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Tech-Readiness-DocuSign-Identify-ID-Verification) feature. And it can be tricky to properly close out the iFrame after the signing ceremony is complete.

From the error messages, it appears that you used `http://www.docusign.com` as your redirect_url attribute in your API call. You need to use a URL that starts with https.